# How to obtain translated full day name from date in Apex?

Tags: apex, date, translation, format

In Apex, the name of the day can be derived from a date using the `format('EEEE')` method:

```java
Datetime targetDate = Datetime.newInstance(2022, 4, 28, 0, 0, 0);
String dayOfWeek = targetDate.format('EEEE');
system.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'DayName: '+dayOfWeek); //Thursday
```

But running this code when Salesforce user language is in French (Français), the name of the day is still returned as "**Thursday**" instead of "**Jeudi**".

The std user field `LanguageLocaleKey` = fr and `LocaleSidKey` = fr_FR_EURO on the user.

Looking for a way of having the translated value in Apex, similar to this solution in LWC (Javascript).

```js
import LANG from '@salesforce/i18n/lang'; //current user language with possible values en-US,fr-FR,...

export default class LwcSample extends LightningElement {
   get dayName(){
      let currentDate = new Date(2022, 3, 28); //April month index = 3
      let weekDay = currentDate.toLocaleDateString(LANG, { weekday: 'long' });
      console.log('DayName: ' + weekDay); //jeudi where user lang = fr-FR
   }
}
```

Based on a date, how can we obtain the day name translated in user language in Apex ?

Comment: Can you clarify what field on user was set? I thought this value got translated.

Comment: The std language field `LanguageLocaleKey` = fr on the user

Comment: @AdrianLarson any idea if this is a potential bug ?